# What fingering should be used for a chromatic scale separated by thirds on piano?

Tags: piano, fingering, exercises, chromatic

I started learning Edvard Grieg's Piano Concerto in A Minor Op 16, and I came across a part of the music that requires my right hand to do the chromatic scale twice at the same time, separated by thirds. That is, one hand is responsible for doing two notes simultaneously separated by thirds and traversing the chromatic scale.

Is there a standard or preferred fingering for this? It would be for the right hand, going down the scale, if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about standards; there are lots of different fingerings for Chopin's Op.25 No.6, for example. The one I'd play in the Grieg concerto (first run) is

1-5, 2-4, 2-3, 1-5, 2-4, 1-5, 2-4, 1-3, 2-4, 2-3, 1-5, 2-4, 1-5, ...

This is a regular fingering: 1-5 always for the white-white pairs, 2-4 -> 2-3 slide is always before the white keys with no black keys between. With this as a starting point, the rest comes out pretty much automatically. The easy 1-5, 2-4 combination gets used a lot.